# UIView initialization with viewModel callback in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I've got a bit of circular problem. See the objective c version for a UIView custom initialiser (or something along these lines):

```
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame data:(MyDataType) myData{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 200)];
    if(self){
       self.viewModel = [[MyViewModel alloc] initwith:self andWithData:myData];
    } 
    return self;
}
```

Now in swift this becomes a suffering. When using the following:

```
init(_ myData: MyDataModel){
        viewModel = MyViewModel(view:self,data:myData)
        super.init(frame:CGRect.zero)
    }
```

Now here is where the problems come up:

1. If I call super.init(frame:CGRect.zero) first then I get an error along the lines of the view model not being set up.
2. If I call the super after the view model initialization, then theres obviously an error because self doesn't exists

Then there is this:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
```

1. How do I initialize the view model if I'm not passing in the data?
2. I would also like to know how to handle the frames issue, for example:

If I have an init method like this:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
}
```

I can instantiate the object like this: myView() and I don't need to pass in a frame and I normally don't need to pass in a frame because the OS sorts itself out. However with:

```
init(_ myData: MyDataModel){
            viewModel = MyViewModel(view:self,data:myData)
            super.init(frame:CGRect.zero)
        }
```

Now requires me to use a frame, I've chosen `CGRect.zero` but is this the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Use `var`, instead of `let`. And avoid of using CGRect.zero for initialization UIView's:

```
import UIKit

class MyDataModel {}

class MyViewModel {
    init(view: UIView, data: MyDataModel) { }
}

class SomeView: UIView {

    fileprivate var viewModel: MyViewModel!

    init(_ myData: MyDataModel){
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 0.1, height: 0.1))
        viewModel = MyViewModel(view: self, data: myData)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        /**
            You can set viewModel somehow or call fatal error
            fatalError("Couldn't Be Created Through The Stroryboard")
         */
    }

    func someMethodWithViewModel() {
        guard let viewModel = viewModel else { return }
        /* Do whatever you need with viewModel */
    }
}
```